# Multiple dialog activities outside app at the same time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I start a new dialog activity from broadcast receiver in my app.
I want this dialog activity to be shown independent of the app (i.e) even when the app is minimized, my broadcast receiver can create the dialog activity and show it outside the app.
I was able to achieve this by setting Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK while starting the activity and by specifying the dialog activity as singleInstance in the manifest file.

Now there can be instances where the broadcast receiver might create two dialog activities at the same time.
How do i achieve this?

Note: the dialog activity has to be show outside the app independently even when the app is running in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` is definitely the wrong approach. Remove that.

What you need to do is to set the task affinity of this `Activity` so that it isn't tightly-coupled to your application. To do that, add

```
android:taskAffinity=""
```

to the `<activity>` tag in the manifest.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was able to achieve it with adding taskAffinity in manifest and starting my activity with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK.

Comment: You probably don't need `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`. I think this will confuse users. If you have 2 of these dialogs up, each in separate tasks, you will see multiple entires in the recent tasks list and you won't be able to tell them apart. It might be better to just have multiple dialog activities in the same task, so that once the user dismisses one of the dialog activities the one underneath it will be shown. Just my suggestion. I try not to use  `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` because it creates a lot of confusion later.